# json: use associative array as data

Tags: jquery, json

In json.php:

```
$data = array ( "filename"  => array (), "datetime"  => array () );
```

The $data array is filled with some data from a loop.

In index.php:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "json.php",
    success: function(data){

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            console.log(data[i].filename);
        });



     }
});
```

I'm trying to print all the filenames from my data object, but they're undefined according to the console. What did I miss?

Comment: plz accept one of the answers if it solved your problem, thx

Answer (score 2):

on php site:

```
$data = array ( "filename"  => array (), "datetime"  => array () );
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

on js site:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "json.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            console.log(item.filename);
        });

     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `json_encode($data)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP developer, but have you checked `data` using Firebug because it's probably not JSON?

If you find out that it's a JSON string you should first do this

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

And for the sake of brevity you could write

```
$.ajax({
    url: "json.php",
    success: function(data){
        data = $.parseJSON(data); // if needed
        $.each(data, function() {
            console.log(this.filename);
        });
     }
});
```